# Math Olympiad Question Probability of being Ahead in voting

Tags: probability, contest-math

The statement of the problem I am facing is:

> Arthur and Bernard participated of an election to take care of a
> building with 100 voters. At the end, 60 people voted in Arthur and 40
> in Bernard. What is the chance that during the investigation of the result of
> the votes, Arthur is always ahead of Bernard?

However, I didn't find a direct way, even though, my idea was to find all sequences, such that Arthur gets 60 votes and the remaining is given to Bernard, as in A-, AAB, ABA, AABA, AAAB, this is, the number of sequences such that **#A's > # B's** and **#A's + #Bs < 101**.

Comment: My idea was to draw a grid with A votes on the x axis and B votes on the y axis. If we can count n=the number of routes from (0,0) to (60,40) where A is always greater than B we will be nearly done - because we can easily calculate m = the total number of routes (100 choose 40) and the required probability is n/m. It's easy to label the number of routes on the grid with the number of routes, but there are too many to do by hand and I can't find (yet) a useful closed form.

Comment: See [Bertrand's Ballot Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_ballot_theorem)

Comment: @lulu great! It would be better I guess for you to post that link as an answer while adding that formula as summary. Then the question could be marked as solved perhaps.

Comment: @InanimateBeing not a fan of link only solutions. Feel free to post it yourself, under Community if you prefer. Or the OP could.

Comment: @lulu, in general I see you tend to answer more via comments than actually posting an answer. Example: quite some of my own doubts/posts that were solved by you but in comments. I find it strange and near-inexplicable but your style is still fine (maybe not wrt EoQS?).